# php form submit not working correctly

Tags: php, html

I have a page in which the user can log in. A php script check the login values.
The problem is, when I enter my details in the form, I get redirected to the .php page but I get a blank screen. When I refresh that screen, it says "Unsuccesfull" because my email and password values aren't set anymore because of the refresh.

Why do I get a blank page after pressing "Log in"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Grippee - Login</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/customtheme.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a class="ui-btn-left" href="index.html" data-icon="back">Terug</a>
                <h1><span>Login</span></h1>
                <a class="ui-btn-right" href="#" data-icon="info">i & &euro;</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-position="relative">
                <div class="loginform">
                    <form id="loginForm" action="login.php" method="POST">
                        <span>Email adres:</span>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
                        <span>Wachtwoord:</span>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></input>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
    $email = "";
    $password = "";
    if (isset($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        echo ($email);
    } 
    else {
        echo("Something is wrong");
    }
    if (isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        echo($password);
    }

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'qq', 'qq', 'qq', 3306);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM Consument WHERE email = '$email' AND wachtwoord = '$password'");
    $rows = $result->num_rows;

    if ($rows == 1)
        echo ("Logged in!");
    else
        echo ("Unsuccesfull!"); 
?>
```

Comment: @fefe If they are enabled, I get extra error lines (expected) after refreshing the page. The problem is when I first navigate to the php page, it turns out blank. I only see data when I refresh the page...

Comment: And how do you expect to debug the reason of blank page?

Comment: @fefe That is what I am wondering myself, and that's why I ask for help. I don't know what to do from now on...

Comment: Your php is not clean, the query looks to have errors

Comment: @fefe I changed 2 things. The code should be working now but the problem persists though.

Comment: Check the error log and see what errors you get. The error logs would give you clues about where you have made an error.

Comment: @Susam I made a change and now I don't have any errors. Still, I need a refresh before the php script actually runs.

Comment: Plus the query runs fine on an other page.

Answer (score 0):

the query is not correct.

use this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE email = " . $email . " AND wachtwoord = " . $password);
```

Comment: I don't even see the .php at first, and after refreshing, my email and password value are empty...

Answer (score 0):

I modified a bit your php. Give a try with it. Even like this is not the best approach but..

```
<?php
   //enable all kind of errors to can debug properly   
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
   error_reporting(-1);

    $email = "";
    $password = "";

    if ( isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        echo ($email);
        echo($password);

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'qq', 'qq', 'qq', 3306);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE email = '".$email."' and wachtwoord = '".$password."'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($rows == 1)
        echo ("Logged in!");
    else
        echo ("Unsuccesfull!"); 

    } 
    else {
        echo("Something is wrong");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm afraid the problem is still here though.

Comment: if you use firebug you can check the post response under the console

Comment: I made a change and now I don't have any errors. Still, I need a refresh before the php script actually runs.